# rsync command fails with jenkin

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, rsync

While am trying to execute rsync command from macOS Catalina terminal i was able to successfully copy the data from volume to local drive

This is the command am using

```
rsync -avxhPE /Volumes/pathtofolder/assets/. ./assets
```

But the same command is not working in Jenkins. Am getting the following error.

```
 + rsync -avxhPE /Volumes/pathtofolder/assets/. ./assets
19:28:22 building file list ... 
19:28:24  0 files...
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/pathtofolder/assets/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
19:28:24 1 file to consider
19:28:24 ./
19:28:24 
19:28:24 sent 83 bytes  received 26 bytes  43.60 bytes/sec
19:28:24 total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
19:28:24 rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
19:28:24 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
19:28:24 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The user who run `jenkins` do not have permission to read the directory. Check this line:

```
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/pathtofolder/assets/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Comment: Romeo : Jenkins run the command as SYSTEM User , and the SYSTEM user has read,write permission on that folder

Comment: Romeo : Am also confused in that part , the jenkins runs on Mac machines and the volume we try to access is a windows machine , will it make any issues ?  while checking the permissions of the volume folder by clicking the right buttom and properties options , i could see that for user SYSTEM the read and write is allowed . is that the right way to ensure the permissions ? or did i missed anythig on that part

Comment: @AnsarSamad, I have not experience with MAC so have no idea about this user. Can you become this user. Also can you check what is the result of `ls -ld /Volumes/pathtofolder/assets/`

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of new user privacy protections in macOS 10.15.  See WWDC 2019 Session 701 [Advances in macOS Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/701/) for all the details.  As a user, you can grant access to the tool by adding it to the list in

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders.
```

Share and Enjoy